# Is there a way to resize a UIButton in Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard

1. How do I get the **0** width to be equal size  with 1 and 2
2. **( . )** to be equal width as 3 and **=** to be equal width with +?

I can't drag the white square (When clicking the UI button) to resize them.

Screenshot of my storyboard:

[image: Screenshot of my storyboard]

Comment: Stacks won't allow you to do it because it takes sizes according to content. Can you show what is your desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Follow Steps**

1. Focus on stack view contain the elements "0 . ="
2. select ". =" element and embed into a stack view
3. StackView properties must be "Alignment = Fill", "Distribution = Fill Equally" and "Spacing" as per other elements 
   [image: check image]

Comment: let me know if you are still facing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

#### Option1

Set the StackView to `Distribution Fill` and then control drag the `0 Button` onto the `. Button`. Select Equal Widths and then set the Multiplier (times 2 since it should be twice the size) in the Size Inspector.

[image] 
[image]

#### Option2

Put the `.Button` and the `= Button` in an equally filled StackView and then the `0 Button` and the StackView in another equally filled StackView. This is probably the better option if it's a 50-50 distribution.